# Want to play 1 of 3 tracks depending on current level

Tags: algorithm, mathematics, haxe

I want to play a gameplay music track depending on what the current level is.

E.g.

1 - Play track 1

2 - Play track 1

3 - Play track 2

4 - Play track 2

5 - Play track 3

repeat...

6 - Play track 1

7 - Play track 1

8 - Play track 2

9 - Play track 2

10 - Play track 3

This is what I have, but problem is track 2 will be used at level 6 when it should be track 1.

```
public static function playGameplayMusic(waveId:Int):Void
{
    var gamePlayTrackId:Int;

    if (waveId % 5 == 0) {
        gamePlayTrackId = 3;
    } else if (waveId % 3 == 0 || waveId % 4 == 0) {
        gamePlayTrackId = 2;
    } else {
        gamePlayTrackId = 1;
    }

    trace('playing gameplay track: ' + gamePlayTrackId);

    SoundPlayer.playMusicByName('gameplay/' + gamePlayTrackId, false);
}
```

**Update:**

Went with this. Thanks for all your contributions!

```
public static function playGameplayMusic(waveId:Int):Void
{
    var gamePlayTrackId:Int = Math.ceil(((waveId - 1) % 5 + 1) / 2);

    SoundPlayer.playMusicByName('gameplay/' + gamePlayTrackId, false);
}
```

Comment: The core of this question seems to be a numeric algorithm that isn't specific to game development, or indeed to playing music, so the title is quite misleading. Any way this could be edited to clarify?

Comment: Do you know what `%` does?

Comment: I knew my question was wrong and yes I know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine a modulo (for the wrap-around) and a division (for the duplication of tracks).  With some testing I got to:

```
static function track(level:Int):Int
{
    return Math.ceil(((level - 1) % 5 + 1) / 2);
}
```

(live example on [Try Haxe](http://try.haxe.org/#C76FE))

The idea is to divide a wrap-around, adjusting for no zeros.  There might be a way to simplify this though.

Comment: Does Haxe not have a `switch` statement that you can just do `switch((level-1)%5)` on? (Please forgive my ignorance if there is no such statement, but I know precisely nothing about Haxe.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, Haxe does have a `switch` statement, and that might make things more [readable](http://try.haxe.org/#89447).  Performance varies between targets, with `Math.ceil` being faster in JS and `switch` in the other platforms I tested.

Answer (score 5):

This question would probably be better suited at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

**That being said:**
You are using the wrong modulo.
Pseudocode:

```
n = waveID % 5;
n == 0 => Track3
n == 1 || n == 2 => Track1
n == 3 || n == 4 => Track2
```

If you use modulo you always have to use the size of you collection/repeating pattern (in this case 5). 
Furthermore I would recommend enumerating the levels beginning at 0, which shifts the above code around to:

```
n = waveID % 5;
n == 0 || n == 1 => Track1
n == 2 || n == 3 => Track2
n == 4 => Track3
```

The cleanest way to do this part is probably (**Edit:** adjusted to HAXE and removed case drop, thanks to jonasmalacofilho):

```
var n = waveID % 5;
switch(n){
case 0:
  gamePlayTrackId = 1;
case 1:
  gamePlayTrackId = 1;
case 2:
  gamePlayTrackId = 2;
case 3:
  gamePlayTrackId = 2;
case 4:
  gamePlayTrackId = 3;
default:
  //throw exception
}
```

Comment: +1, nice answer. Though I would hesitate to recommend people new to programming use case drop-through. It's dangerous.

Comment: In Haxe, case body expressions [never](http://haxe.org/manual/expression-switch.html) fall through.

Comment: @jonasmalacofilho Thanks, edited it. I don't know HAXE though, is the rest of the syntax correct?

Comment: @Almo Registered here to say this: I would never recommend **anyone** to drop cases. `//should not occur` is almost as long as `raise Exception()`, or whatever the language-equivalent is. If you do a mistake only with every 1000th switch-routine you set up, this is still saving you a lot of time.

Comment: @FooBar I guess he meant that I attached multiple cases to the same statement, which i edited out.

Comment: @LukeG Well, I'm reacting to the `default: Nothing` code.

Comment: @FooBar I guess he meant that I attached multiple cases to the same statement, which i edited out. "Dropping"  cases as you meant it isn't nice style, but in this case I used it to demonstratr that all mathematical possible cases are covered and if it occurs there is a problem with the modulo implementation.  I left exception throwing out because I don't know the corresponding syntax in Haxe

Answer (score 4):

I don't know enough haxe to make this code better, but I would probably just do

```
var tracklist = [3, 1, 1, 2, 2];
gamePlayTrackId = tracklist[waveId % 5];
```

You can probably improve this by making tracklist static or any number of ways.
I'm still learning though, so look at the comments before you implement anything.

Comment: +1, this should be the accepted answer. You *might* want to consider using `tracklist[(waveId - 1) % 5]` and moving the `3` to the end of the list, just for the sake of clarity, though.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting problems with higher numbers being multiples of more than one of the numbers you check. 6 is not just going to trip the last else, it will also trip the `% 3 == 0` one. I might do it this way:

```
StartGame()
{
    m_musicLevel = 1;
    m_track = playGameplayMusic(1);
}

NextLevel()
{
    m_musicLevel++;
    if(m_musicLevel > 5)
    {
        m_musicLevel = 1;
    }
    m_track = playGameplayMusic(m_musicLevel);
}
```

This means your `playGameplayMusic` function will only ever see levels 1-5. It's not super-elegant, but it's easy to understand and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If your levels are procedural / infinite, then the using the chosen method is good.

If you have a limited set of levels (i.e., only 10), then just associate the track choice with the level, hard-coded or preferably stored in the data that is loaded per level.